# Prove if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = 0$, $f$ has a global maximum and minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Prove if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = 0$, then $f$ has a global maximum and minimum.

This is the exact question posed, but wouldn't a function such as the bell curve be a counterexample as it would only have a global maximum?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I agree.  But maybe the question poser understands "has a global minimum" to mean "has a global minimum over the extended reals $\overline{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$."  If this is the case, your counterexample has a global minimum, as well, at $x=\pm\infty$.

Comment: As you have already been told, you are right. I just want to add that the statement becomes true if we add the extra hypothesis that $0\in f(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: The statement also becomes true if we change the word _and_ to _or_..

Comment: It might have been a formulation error then indeed. Thanks for clearing up the confusion. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score -1):

A continuous function does not blow up anywhere else except at infinity. Since the limit is $0$ at infinity, one can conclude that $f(\mathbb{R})=]a,b[$.

Comment: Doesn't $f(\Bbb{R})=]a,b[$ mean that $a$ and $b$ are *not* in the range of $f$? Then this says that $f$ does *not* have a global minimum or maximum...